# Possibility of Proving Quotient is Not a Natural Number

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

If we define $F\left(x
\right) = LCM\left(1,2,3,...,x\right)$ where $x\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x>1$ is it possible to prove
$$\frac{F\left(x\right)^2}{F\left(2x\right)}\not\in\mathbb{N}$$ specifically without using Bertrand's Postulate? I'm sorry if this is a stupid question but I have had no luck in trying to find a solution not relying on the fact that there is at least one prime number in the denominator that is not in the numerator. If it is possible to prove without Bertrand's Postulate I would appreciate a hint over a full solution, but all the same thank you for your time.

Comment: This equivalent to Bertrand's Postulate. I don't see how you can prove this without b.Postulate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This claim is actually equivalent to Bertrand's postulate.  You already showed why Bertrand's postulate implies your claim so we only need to prove the other direction.

Let $u_p(x)$ be the largest power of $p$ less than $x$.  The only way that your claim can be true is if $u_p(2x) > 2u_p(x)$ for some prime $p$ and positive integer $x$.  If $u_p(x) \geq 1$ then $$u_p(2x) \leq u_p(px) = u_p(x)+1 \leq u_p(x)+u_p(x) = 2u_p(x).$$  So your claim can only be true if $u_p(x) = 0$ and $u_p(2x) \geq 1$ for some $x$ and $p$.  Hence if your claim is true for each $x$, then so is Bertrand's postulate!